# how can I change order of <tr> tags in the table C#?

Tags: c#, html

If I have a table in .aspx

```
<table id="table" >
  <tr id="first" runat="server"> blablabla>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="second" runat="server">
       <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can I change  order from second to first in the code behind?

I tried to wrap tr with placeholders and hide/display them accordingly, but it doesn't allow me to do that as I get duplicate IDs inside these rows. And I can't use javascript for that..

Comment: You can indeed use Javascript to change the DOM after the page loads.

Comment: @Mike Atlas - he probably means that he is not allowed.

Comment: @Mike Atlas  can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

As you have not set either `tr` or `table` as server side code (by using a `runat="server"` attribute), they are not visible to the code behind and it cannot change the ordering.

In aspx:

```
<table id="table" runat="server">
    <tr id="first" runat="server">
        <td>blablabla</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="second" runat="server">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In code behind:

```
var row = table.Rows[0]; // get reference to first row
table.Rows.Remove(row);  // remove it
table.Rows.Add(row);     // Add again, at the end (default)
```

Comment: I set that, sorry. So how can I change order on the server side?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is static markup rather than a server side control (none of the tags are set to `runat="server"`), the server side C# code can't modify them.